# wrong boolean result within if statement

Tags: ios, objective-c

This code should print **false** to a console but it print **true**

```
NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.tag = 7;

if(label.tag <= (data.count - 1)) {
    NSLog(@"true");
} else {
    NSLog(@"false");
}
```

anyone can explain this?

Comment: What is data.count value? can you show value stored in data array?

Comment: Use `< data.count` and retry.

Comment: It doesn't look like you already tried to check your values inside the debugger otherwise you would have seen why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data.count` is `0` but it is an unsigned integer (`NSUInteger`).

`(data.count - 1)` which is `0 - 1` in this case won't be equal to `-1` because the integer is unsigned. It will be the maximum integer (`4294967295`). We call this *integer underflow*.

You can fix it easily

```
label.tag + 1 <= data.count
```

With unsigned integer, you always have to take care with subtraction.
Another way to fix this is using a cast to signed integer:

```
label.tag <= ((NSInteger) data.count) - 1
```